# Optimizing one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run query to get some data from the DB. The thing is the query which I use works but takes a very long time.

```
SELECT SHH1.CUST_NO,
       SHH1.CUST_NAME,
       ADDR.BVADDREMAIL 
FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER SHH1
INNER JOIN ADDRESS ADDR ON (SHH1.CUST_NO=ADDR.CEV_NO)
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER CUST ON (SHH1.CUST_NO=CUST.CUS_NO)
WHERE CUST.HOLD = 0
AND SHH1.CUST_NO IN (SELECT SHH2.CUST_NO 
                     FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER SHH2
                     GROUP BY SHH2.CUST_NO 
                     HAVING Max(SHH2.IN_DATE) < '20120101')
GROUP BY SHH1.CUST_NO,
         SHH1.CUST_NAME,
         ADDR.BVADDREMAIL
```

I am not very good at this so was wondering if any of you guys could help me? Thanks.

Comment: What indexes do you currently have?  Can you show the [query plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)?

Comment: Please include table creation scripts so that we'll know the datatypes of each column, `indexes`, `PKs`, `FKs`. Also include the query plan as pointed out by @PinnyM

Comment: Is `CUST_NAME` on `SALES_HISTORY_HEADER` or `CUSTOMER`?

Comment: show us your explain analyze

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the sub-select. the following should give you the same results:

```
SELECT SHH1.CUST_NO,SHH1.CUST_NAME,ADDR.BVADDREMAIL 
FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER SHH1
INNER JOIN ADDRESS ADDR ON (SHH1.CUST_NO=ADDR.CEV_NO)
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER CUST ON (SHH1.CUST_NO=CUST.CUS_NO)
WHERE CUST.HOLD = 0
GROUP BY SHH1.CUST_NO,SHH1.CUST_NAME,ADDR.BVADDREMAIL
HAVING Max(SHH1.IN_DATE) < '20120101'
```

Comment: The sub-select should not be a problem as it is non-correlated (does not reference the external context), unless [subquery materialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `CUST_NAME` is on `CUSTOMER`, try:

```
SELECT CUST.CUS_NO CUST_NO,
       CUST.CUST_NAME,
       ADDR.BVADDREMAIL 
FROM CUSTOMER CUST
JOIN ADDRESS ADDR ON CUST.CUS_NO=ADDR.CEV_NO
LEFT JOIN SALES_HISTORY_HEADER SHH 
       ON CUST.CUS_NO=SHH.CUST_NO AND SHH.IN_DATE >= '20120101'
WHERE CUST.HOLD = 0 AND SHH.CUST_NO IS NULL
GROUP BY CUST.CUS_NO, ADDR.BVADDREMAIL
```

Comment: This query is different, functionnally - but I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @Sebas: It's functionally different if `CUST_NAME` is actually on `SALES_HISTORY_HEADER`, but not if it's on `CUSTOMER` - hence the comment on the original question and the explicitly stated assumption at the start of this answer.

Comment: My comment because you are using LEFT JOIN on SHH, and also using SHH.CUST_NO IS NULL which is pretty much not in the original query at all. Maybe you meant cust_no IS NOT NULL instead?

Comment: However I think that your left join on SSH is not at all the same than the subquery he did, with the max(date).

Comment: @Sebas: both queries exclude customers with SHH records on or after 01 Jan 2012 - the OP by inner joining to an inline view of customers whose maximum SHH in_date value is less than 01 Jan 2012, while this query does so by LEFT JOINing to SHH records on or after 01 Jan 2012, then excluding customers where such records exists - this approach is similar to a NOT EXISTS clause, but should work faster in MySQL.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see you reversed the logic, my bad. Please let me insist however on the fact that you would include a customer with ssh.in_date = '20111201', where he would not in the original query since maybe for this customer there's also a row with ssh.in_date = '20120201'

Comment: @Sebas: if a customer has SHH records with in_dates of both 20111201 and 20120201 then it will be excluded from this query by the existence of the later record (left outer join, exclude existing records). If a customer has SHH records with in_dates of only 20111201 then it will be included in the results from this query and the original.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Excution Plan which part of the query has the major cost of execution. That will likely indicate where is the problem. The next step I would perform is to review indexes creation. Please recall clustered index is created by default over PKs but it is also a good practice to create non-clustered index over the FKs and any potential field you may have particular interest. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Mark Bannister's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278290/244935) that the OP should do `FROM CUSTOMER` instead `FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER`.

So, Assuming `CUST_NAME` is on `CUSTOMER`, I would do the following:

```
SELECT CUST.CUS_NO,
       CUST.CUST_NAME,
       ADDR.BVADDREMAIL 
FROM CUSTOMER CUST
JOIN ADDRESS ADDR ON CUST.CUS_NO = ADDR.CEV_NO
WHERE CUST.HOLD = 0
AND CUST.CUS_NO IN (SELECT SHH.CUST_NO 
                    FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER SHH
                    GROUP BY SHH.CUST_NO 
                    HAVING Max(SHH.IN_DATE) < '20120101')
```

Note that [subquery materialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) must be active for MySQL to optimize the sub-select.

Comment: I wasn't saying that the OP necessarily **should** take the customer's name from the customer table - I was asking if it actually **was** stored on that table. (Conceivably, old versions of the customer's name -such as their maiden name- **might** be stored on the Sales History Header table; it depends on whether the purpose of the query is to return the customer's current name, or all their historic names. Similarly, the `BVADDREMAIL` may or may not vary with multiple adddresses for the same customer.)

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. Then probably my answer is wrong, if for nothing else, then for the `BVADDREMAIL`. With the _should_ I meant though that assuming the `CUST_NAME` was intended to be on the `CUSTOMER` table, **then** the `FROM CUSTOMER` approach would have been a more intuitive way to write the query.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing some rows before joining

```
SELECT S.CUST_NO,
      ,S.Cust_NAME
      ,A.BVADDREMAIL
FROM CUSTOMER C
    INNER JOIN SALES_HISTORY_HEADER S ON (CUST.HOLD = 0 AND S.CUST_NO=C.CUS_NO)
        INNER JOIN ADDRESS A ON (S.CUST_NO=A.CEV_NO)
GROUP BY S.CUST_NO,S.CUST_NAME,A.BVADDREMAIL
HAVING Max(S.IN_DATE) < '20120101'
```

My update on [StevieG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54555/stevieg)'s answer